# React speech-to-text and text-to-speech

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm trying to create an app to convert user voice to google assistant voice. Currently i use this module https://github.com/Riley-Brown/react-speech-to-text it's a speech to text but it doesn't say that this can convert the text to speech so i need to look for another module.

currently here's my development so far

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gxwred?file=index.tsx

i can convert the audio to text, how can i convert that text to audio?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Comment: thanks, by searching that i found this https://github.com/MikeyParton/react-speech-kit

Comment: For TS and React 18 support use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tts-react.